# WITH Clause SQL throws error when deleting rows but works fine for select statment

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, sql-delete

```
with de_duplicate (ad_id, id_type, lat, long) AS (
select ad_id, id_type, lat, long,
Row_Number() over(partition by ad_id,id_type, lat, long) AS duplicate_count
from tempschema.temp_test)
select * from de_duplicate;
```

Above runs successful but when I try to perform a delete operation

```
with de_duplicate(ad_id, id_type, lat, long) AS 
(
select ad_id, id_type, lat, long,
Row_Number() over(partition by ad_id,id_type, lat, long) AS duplicate_count
from tempschema.temp_test
)
delete from de_duplicate where duplicate_count > 1;
```

It throws an error 
Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "delete" 
Position: 190;

I am running these queries on a redshift cluster. Any thoughts?

Comment: This syntax is not allowed in Redshift.

Comment: who normally deletes over a CTE anyone?

Comment: This is a temporary table for which I don't need a backup. Any help with the right syntax @GordonLinoff is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider converting CTE into a subquery and add the *unique_id* to match against outer query:

```
DELETE FROM tempschema.temp_test
WHERE unique_id NOT IN
  (SELECT sub.unique_id
   FROM 
      (SELECT unique_id, ad_id, id_type, lat, long,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ad_id, id_type, lat, long) AS dup_count
        FROM tempschema.temp_test) sub
   WHERE sub.dup_count > 1)
```

Alternatively, consider deleting using an aggregate subquery:

```
DELETE FROM tempschema.temp_test
WHERE unique_id NOT IN
   (SELECT MIN(unique_id)
    FROM tempschema.temp_test
    GROUP BY ad_id, id_type, lat, long)
```

Of course both assumes you have a *unique_id* in table but can be adjusted if not.

Comment: Select statement works fine but delete statement throws the similar error.

Comment: For which approach -both? If first, then that's interesting. Redshift tends to follow Postgre's SQL dialect but I guess CTEs are not allowed in `DELETE`. Consider moving entire CTE in `FROM` clause of subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, it's a common problem, but the approach has 2 issues:

1) you're trying to delete from the result of your query (`de_duplicate`), not from the source table (`tempschema.temp_test`). Even if you identify duplicates in `de_duplicate` statement it has nothing to do with the source table `tempschema.temp_test`.

2) CTE (`WITH` clause) doesn't work directly with `DELETE` and `UPDATE`, they require joined subqueries.

The two possible approaches in your case:

1) use a joined subquery if you have a unique ID and duplication criteria in your table (`val` in the test case below, so id=3 and id=4 are duplicates):

```
create table test1 (id integer, val integer);
insert into test1 values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,3);

delete from test1 using (
    select *
    from (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by val order by id desc)
        from test1
    )
    where row_number>1
) s
where test1.id=s.id;
```

2) create a cleaned staging table and swap the tables:

```
create table tempschema.temp_test_staging (like tempschema.temp_test);
insert into tempschema.temp_test_staging
select *
from (
    select ad_id, id_type, lat, long,
    Row_Number() over(partition by ad_id,id_type, lat, long) AS duplicate_count
    from tempschema.temp_test
)
where duplicate_count=1;
alter table tempschema.temp_test rename to temp_test_old;
alter table tempschema.temp_test_staging rename to temp_test;
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexYes,  as I am trying delete duplicates, I have selected only the rows with dup_count as 1. I think the problem is solved for me.